# Subexpression inside Regex

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have the following Regex which I use for syntax highlighting:

```
static Regex inQuotes = new Regex("(\"|\').*(\"|\')", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

However, there is an issue. Whenever, I encounter a text like:

`"text_example1'` or
`'text_example2"`

it actually changes the color of the text, because these two cases are considered a match. What I want to do is to change this Regex in a way that I can replace the second `(\"|\')` with something else.

I was thinking about subexpressions and I was wondering on how I could change it so that once I get the first match (`"` or `'`), then the last match must be the same as the first match instead of `"` or `'`.

Comment: Do you have any escaped entities inside the quoted strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\"|\').*?(\1)
```

You can use `backreferencing` here to achieve what you want.Also make your expression `non greedy` `.*?` from greedy `.*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nM7nT5/3

```
string strRegex = @"(\""|\').*?(\1)";
```

Comment: I had to write `\\1` because I was getting a `Error Unrecognized escape sequence`. Other than that, it seems to be perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @OC_ it would be `\\1` if you dont use `@`  or verbatim mode

Comment: @vks: `string strRegex = @"([""']).*?(\1)";`

Comment: @stribizhev yup dat would also do :)